# Project dll error in Visual Studio 2013 output upon Build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dll, build

When I build my project, I get this message in the Output window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ProjectX, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  ProjectX -> C:\Users\Alfred\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ProjectX2015\ProjectX\ProjectX\bin\ProjectX.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I think it started after an `update-package`. It compiles but I'm starting to wonder what the 2nd line mean:

```
1>  ProjectX -> C:\Users\Alfred\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ProjectX2015\ProjectX\ProjectX\bin\ProjectX.dll
```

**Is this a real error or just something to ignore?**

Below is my  `ProjectX.dll.config` (sanitized):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\XXX.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyProject;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
   <appSettings>
       <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
       <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
       <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
       <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
       <add key="SecurityKey" value="XXX" />
   </appSettings>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpModules>
    <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
    <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="XXX" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept" publicKeyToken="XXX" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.1.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="XXX" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="XXX" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You have posted output that shows a successful build. What error are you talking about? What message were you getting before?

Comment: The 2nd line in the output mentions the project dll: `1>  ProjectX -> C:\Users\Alfred\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ProjectX2015\ProjectX\ProjectX\bin\ProjectX.dll`. Before, the project would simply build without this line.

Comment: Are you sure that those were successful builds? Please take a look at my answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of the output indicates that a build for a project (named "ProjectX", with "Debug Any CPU" configuration) is started. On the second line, it then outputs the location of the resulting binary. Finally, on the third line, it shows build results for all projects in the current solution.

This is standard output for a successful build of one project. Depending on the complexity of the project, there will sometimes be more lines, but lines 1 and 3 will always be there. The line 2 that shows the location of the output file will only be present in case of a successful build.